# Sort by Clicking on Column Headers in QML TableView

Tags: qt, qml, qtableview

I am trying to create a table in QML, connected to a model, which allows sorting asc/desc by clicking on the column header.  I have created a TableView in QML, connected to QSortFilterProxyModel, connected to QAbstractTableModel, and so far so good.  But I'm stuck on how to add sorting by clicking on column headers in QML.

In the documentation for QSortFilterProxyModel, it says that in order to sort the contents of the accompanying view, you have to set the sortingEnabled property in the accompanying QTableView (could be a QListView, QTableView, or QTreeView) to true using setSortingEnabled(bool enable). Enabling this property seems to magically add click to sort capabilities to the columns...in C++'s QTableView.

However, I'm working in QML.  How can I achieve the same for my QML TableView?  I thought about subclassing the QTableView and exposing it to QML but that seems like a lot of work for something which is probably already available somehow.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: This is a "how to" question...so there is no MRE.  Looking for advice on how to solve a problem.

Comment: If necessary since it depends on for example which TableView you use (QQC1 or QQC2)

Comment: I don't know which to use - but based on your reply I'm discovering differences relating to sorting.  I assume I should use QQC2 if it replaces QQC1 (though QQC1 would make it easier)

Answer (score 2):

you can use QtQuick.Controls v1 TableView and handle sort event manually at SortIndicatorColumnChanged and SortIndicatorOrderChanged signals.

Comment: I see that TableView has moved form QtQuick.Controls v1 to QtQuick v2.x  Does that mean v1 has been deprecated and I should use v2 tableview?  If so, what happened to the SortIndicatorXX properties?  Am I supposed to recreate this functionality myself?

Comment: QtQuick.Control v1 will be depricated at Qt 6.
https://ddgobkiprc33d.cloudfront.net/a48189e5-9255-4d66-a946-55c5978a759c.png

Comment: the hardest job is to create a few (same count to headers) mouse areas for catching mouse click events on every header item. but you can use the tableview source code to create a new tableview with your customized features.